# how to add subtotal and grand total column in r

Tags: r

I'm looking for examples or ideas on how I might display a data table in a. Rmd document that has grouped totals at multiple levels. So, in the example following, the date, names, qty, rate, and value have a total at the items level.

Following I just crafted an example to illustrate what I mean:

```
names <- c('note','pen','book','note','pen','book')
qty <- c(150, 100, 200, 50, 150, 75)
date <- c('1-mar-2019','1-mar-2019','1-mar-2019', '2-mar-2019','2-mar-2019','2-mar-2019')
rate <- c(10, 5, 20, 10, 5, 20)

stationary <- data.frame(date, names, qty, rate)

stationary$value = stationary$qty*stationary$rate
```

and I want my result like this below snap,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtP5P.png)

Comment: Please add the desired results in form of a table instead of a picture.

Comment: click the button enter image description here

Comment: We all understand how the link works, but it's helpful to see text versions of data we can copy & paste, not pictures of tables.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: UPDATED CODE FOR FORMATTING**

Use `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)

stationary <- stationary %>% 
    mutate(value = rate*qty)

stationary1 <- stationary %>%
    group_by(names) %>% 
    summarise(qty = sum(qty), value = sum(value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(names = paste0(names, " total")) %>% 
    bind_rows(stationary)

stationary1 %>%
    filter(grepl("total", names)) %>%
    summarise(qty = sum(qty),
              value = sum(value)) %>% 
    mutate(names = "Total (Grand)") %>% 
    bind_rows(stationary1) %>% 
    arrange(names) %>% 
    select(date, names, qty, rate, value) %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>%
    replace_na(list(date = "", names = "", qty = "", rate = "", value = ""))
```

Results look like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   date       names         qty   rate  value
   <chr>      <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 1-mar-2019 book          200   20    4000 
 2 2-mar-2019 book          75    20    1500 
 3 ""         book total    275   ""    5500 
 4 1-mar-2019 note          150   10    1500 
 5 2-mar-2019 note          50    10    500  
 6 ""         note total    200   ""    2000 
 7 1-mar-2019 pen           100   5     500  
 8 2-mar-2019 pen           150   5     750  
 9 ""         pen total     250   ""    1250 
10 ""         Total (Grand) 725   ""    8750
```

Comment: The OP wants a total of the value column, not qty or rate. Presumably, rate wouldn't make sense to just sum anyway

Comment: how to replace "NA" to Blank your result.

Comment: You would have to turn the tibble in its entirety into a character and then gsub NA with “ “

Comment: If you are running the code from the point of creating the data.frame from your code (and question) to my code, I did not get an error.

Comment: Sometimes you have to restate the original data for codes to work. It's sometimes just hinky.

Comment: @sathishkumar could you checkmark my code so I know it is closed?